# UIScrollView indicator always show?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

its possible to make UIScrollView indicator always show? and not only when scrolling!

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so. I checked the reference for the class, and it's not mentioned.

Comment: **To manually workaround, see:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890158/8740349

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't. This is part of the interface guidelines. What you can do alternatively is flash them in some sensible circumstances (the view becomes visible, moves onto the screen, or similar) using the [`- (void)flashScrollIndicators`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/flashScrollIndicators) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom scroll bar: 
https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

To always show the scroll bar you just need to do this:

```
brScrollBar =[BRScrollBarController initForScrollView:self.tableView
                                               onPosition:kIntBRScrollBarPositionRight
                                                 delegate:self];
brScrollBar.scrollBar.hideScrollBar = NO;
```

The scroll bar has many features, and its draggable.