# Scroll Indicators Visibility

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

Is there any way to make scroll indicators visible throughout the whole application ?[Scroll Indicators are visible only when I touch the scroll view area.]

Regards

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290813/uiscrollview-indicator-always-show and according to guidelines you cannot do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a timer and call

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Or manually call

```
- (void)flashScrollIndicators;
```

Comment: Right, it's a workaround. Better if you do it on separated thread.

Comment: Sorry but what to tight in "- (void)flashScrollIndicators" ?

Comment: If I saw any developers I know use this approach, I'd smack them upside the head.

Comment: @Götze call manually `[yourScrollview flashScrollIndicators];`

Answer (score 0):

You can make them flash but that's it. You can't force an "always visible" state. Unless you code your own scrollbars entirely, just mimicking the look of the default ones.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't: this go against the interface guideline. You can flash though the indicators as it has been already mentioned by other here with the : `- (void)flashScrollIndicators;`.