# How to display vertical scroll indicator always in react native scrollview

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am trying to display vertical scroll indicator always. Because I have 4 pages in my screen, But, After loading screen and scroll first page, The vertical scroll indicator is disappearing which is default behaviour of scrollview. So, I have try to show some **flashScrollIndicators()** But, still it is disappearing.

```
  setScrollView = (scrollView) => {
    // NOTE: scrollView will be null when the component is unmounted
    this.scrollView = scrollView;
    this.scrollView.flashScrollIndicators();
  };


  render() {

return (
      <ScrollView ref={this.setScrollView} style={{ marginTop: 10, flexGrow: 1, flex: 1 }} contentInset={{ bottom: 20 }}>
   );
 }
```

Any suggestions, My requirement is I have to display scroll indicator always in my screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - How to make permanent the vertical scrollbar of the ScrollView component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920804/react-native-how-to-make-permanent-the-vertical-scrollbar-of-the-scrollview-co)

Comment: It is not like duplicate, I have already tried with flashScrollIndicators() But it is not working, So, That is why raised query here.

Comment: Yes it is.  It's exactly the same question, and as the answer in this post says : "There is no known way to disable hiding the indicator without writing native code"

Answer (score -1):

flashScrollIndicators() will **flash** the indicator for one or two seconds. You would need to keep calling it to see it (for example with **setInterval**). But this will make it flash like a Christmas tree, since it will flash every-time it is called, not stay solid.

If what you want the bar to be always solid, then you could use [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015595/695340) for iOS (without native code). Android has the **persistentScrollbar** prop, which is simple enough to use.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Do you have any idea about below query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010417/how-to-apply-different-styles-dynamically-for-matching-text-from-a-dynamic-parag