# ScrollBar always visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I found great piece of code under the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697215/make-scrollbar-always-visible-on-uiscrollview).

But in my case there is more to do. 
My main `VC` is a `UITableViewController`. Controller can display two type of cells. One of them (`MyCell`) is having a subview of type `UITextView` (`textView`). The size of it's text is based on `fontSize` variable. I have two buttons that can lower or greater the `fontSize`, then both reloads the `tableView`. According to the link above and having in mind that `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, I made my piece of code I placed in `didEndDisplayingCell`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell.class == [ConduiteTableCellView class])
    {
        ConduiteTableCellView *conduiteCell = (ConduiteTableCellView *)cell;
        for (UIView *view in conduiteCell.textView.subviews)
        {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                if (view.alpha == 0 && view.frame.size.width < 10)
                {
                    view.alpha = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        [conduiteCell.textView flashScrollIndicators];
    }
}
```

But after the `[self.tableView reloadData];` nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Shall I place my code in some other method?

Comment: Do you sure that the code inside if statement is called?

Comment: Yes. I made 'NSLog' for debugging purposes, it prints proper text from proper 'cell.textView'.

Comment: Have you tried to do it in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: My code placed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` flashes the scroll bar, but doesn't make it stay opaque

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[conduiteCell.textView flashScrollIndicators];` and it will work.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (cell.class == [ConduiteTableCellView class])
  {
    ConduiteTableCellView *conduiteCell = (ConduiteTableCellView *)cell;
    for (UIView *view in conduiteCell.textView.subviews)
    {
      if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
      {
        if (view.alpha == 0 && view.frame.size.width < 10)
        {
          view.alpha = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. I guess I have messed up searching for scroll bar inside my `textView` or I placed it in wrong method, elsewhere I don't know what's happening :v

Comment: I have created a project and tried your code. it works if i remove that line.

Comment: And what if you scroll down or up. Does it stay visible?

Comment: If i scroll tableView up or down, it’s still visible

Comment: It’s not about the tableView, it’s about scrolling the textView. TableView has scrollable content disabled. If text is bigger than textView frame, then scroll bar should be shown and textView should be scrollable

Comment: I tried add observer for `alpha` and `layer.opacity` keyPath and change them to 1 if they are changed but scrollbar was still invisible when i scroll. Seem like we don't have any way to keep it stay visible when scrolling.

Comment: So I guess there is only a DIY scroll bar left for me. Thanks a lot!