# React Native - How to make permanent the vertical scrollbar of the ScrollView component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a React Native app which has a screen containing a list of several items the user can see. I wrapped up the elements by using a `ScrollView` component and it works fine as shown below:

[image]

However, I'd like to have the vertical scrollbar always visible just to let the user know he can see more items than the ones shown in the first place. I've read the [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview) documentation but it seems that there is not an option to make it happen.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve that or perhaps a workaround to make it intuitive to the user that there is a scroll on the list?

Comment: there is no way to make it visible for all the time

Comment: You might want to have a message at the bottom to notice user, like "Scroll down for more" and hide it when user is scrolling down.

Comment: What did you end up with? I have the same request from a client of mine.

Answer (score 3):

This works, but only on Android:

```
persistentScrollbar={true}
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#persistentscrollbar-android

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to showing the scroll indicator constantly that is available in React Native is flashing the indicator. You can obtain a reference to the scrollview and call the `flashScrollIndicators()` method. There is no known way to disable hiding the indicator without writing native code. If you want to go down that path, you could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890158/8207842) for iOS.