# Make scrollbars always visible in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIScrollView - showing the scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar)

How to make `scrollbars` always visible in `uiscrollview`. I used the `flashscrollindicators` it does not make any sense.

I used this code to enable scroll indicator

```
hscroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
```

but the scrollbars are visible only after I start scrolling the `uiscrollview`.

I want to make the scrollbars always visible in uiscrollview

Comment: This link contains some stuff that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290813/uiscrollview-indicator-always-show

Comment: **To manually workaround, see:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890158/8740349

Answer (score 3):

You can flash them but there isn't an option to make them always visible:

```
[myScrollView flashScrollIndicators];
```

Although a possible workaround is described in [question 1888647](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar)