# UIScrollBar scrollbars don't appear - XCode5

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, scrollbar, xcode5

I can't seem to get the scrollbars to appear in any UIScrollbar I am using :/ …

XCodeVersion 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Is there something I have to do?

In interface builder: Scroll View Style = Default … Scroll Indicators = Shows Horizontal Indicator

I've tried changing these values.

I'm setting the frame and contentSize programatically.

The scrollview works fine otherwise.

Is this something that's changed with iOS7 SDK?

Any help would be appreciated!!! Thanks!!! :D

Comment: have you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290813/uiscrollview-indicator-always-show

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with Interface Builder. I was able to get the scrollbars to display by creating the UIScrollView programatically.

I've found an issue programatically actually … the following code causes the horizontal scrollbars to disappear:

```
documentsScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
documentsScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```