# How to enable UIScrollView scroll indicator always visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with dimension 320*320,i want to show the vertical scroll indicator if the contentsize is greater than the frame height or always shown. I know that setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator to YES would show the indicator while scrolling . Is it possible to show the vertical indicator without scrolling or always.

Comment: This might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar

Comment: [Similar Question answered here][1] , try this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290813/uiscrollview-indicator-always-show?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView - showing the scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar)